# How to do Caching only for specific IP's, in Nginx or Rails

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, cache

We have a Rails 2.3.8 app running on a nginx/passenger server. Recently the crawlers generate a huge load on us. We'd like to turn on **page caching ONLY for crawlers** (specific IP addresses), i.e., crawlers get static pages which expire every day. Questions are:

- shall we do it in Nginx or Rails?
- how to achieve this IP-wise caching strategy

I googled for nginx and rails, but no luck so far.  Appreciate any inputs!

Answer (score 0):

I would instead look at the `User-Agent` string to detect crawlers. You can then use either rewrites in Nginx or view logic in Rails to display the desired content. Either way works, it's just a matter of what technology you are most familiar with.

Comment: thanks tylerl. I played with nginx rewrite, and finally got it to work with Rails page caching. However, I'm forced to give this up because there are over 100 million pages, and the cache size, ext3 file number limits and cache expiration are headaches. Need to find a more advanced way to do this.